# Prevent focusing whole node with children

Tags: javascript, dom, focus, preventdefault

*The problem:* If current activeElement is `input#1`, when pressing tab it jumps to `input#2`, but I want to prevent the whole `div[tabindex=-1]` with children being focusable.

```
<div>
  <input id="1" type="text"> // jump from here
  <div tabindex="-1">
    <input id="2" type="text">
    <input id="3" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<button>any focusable element</button> // to here
```

How to achieve that if next focusable element is unknown?

Comment: can you just mark your inputs as disabled?

Comment: you have to set tabindex="-1" for every single child element...

Answer (score 0):

you can use for this `contenteditable` attribute and then disable this after unfocus

```js
function edit(e){
  e.target.setAttribute("contenteditable",true);
}

function unedit(e){
  e.target.setAttribute("contenteditable",false);
}

[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll(".unselect > div"),0).forEach((el)=>{
  el.addEventListener("click",edit);
  el.addEventListener("blur",unedit);
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="1" type="text"> // jump from here
  <div tabindex="-1" class="unselect">
    <div id="2" >editable</div>
    <div id="3" >editable</div>
  </div>
    <input id="4" type="text"> // jump from here
</div>
```

Comment: Sibling div might be a big component with lots of children. I'd don't want mark them all with 'unselect'

Comment: i change selector to ".unselect > div" and now you don't need add class for all